# Multi line and style Android button with image

Tags: android, android-layout, button

My goal is to make button with a rounded image on the left without padding and a multi line text on the right where the 2 lines have different style(color/font). Like this:
[image: Target button]

My problems are:

- I don't know how to implement the multi line button text
- The image corners are not rounded on the left
- The image is bigger than requested

See my result:
[image: My button]

My code is the following:

buttonshape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#F7F7F7" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <size android:width="270dp"
          android:height="60dp" />
</shape>
```

myActivity.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/parkingBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="82dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/parking"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:text="Parking"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textDirection="ltr"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/otherBtn" />
```

**Update:**
I changed to CardView and the result is almost fine. Thanks the tip for @pouya. The problem is that the rounded corners are not visible on the image.

card_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape15"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/parking" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Parking"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="Pay without coins" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the result is:
[image]

(I have changed the border color and radius for better visibility)

**Update 2:**
Even closer to the final result. Now border is present, only the shadow is missing:

layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape15" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/parking" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:text="Parking"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Pay without coins"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

To solve the shadow problem I have tried to use layer-list in the background.xml but it gives ugly shadows. Wrapping everything again inside a CardView and set the elevation gives better result but not as perfect as the reference layout has.

Comment: Can't you just design a custom layout and add onClickListener

Comment: is the text one complete string?

Comment: With custom layout I was able to solve the multi line problem but the image corners were still wrong and I lost the button shadow as well.

Comment: The text is 2 different string

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `CardView` as parent view with `card_view:cornerRadius=5dp` and then in that a `LinearLayout` so it would look something like this .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:background="@color/black"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:theme="@style/light_list_item"
card_view:cornerRadius=5dp>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cost"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="benefit"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

note that I think you should use background for `ImageView`.

**edit** for shadow issue please place a parent for `cardView` that should be either `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` . I haven't test it my self but I am quite sure that it would work.

hope this helps please comment if there is something wrong with this.

Comment: This CardView idea is good but still have one small issue. See my updated post with code and screenshot.

Comment: what do you mean I can't see it? with lower shadow and corner radius I think they are exactly the same. if not you could use scaletype="fitXY" on image view . try it and keep me informed or explain more please.

Comment: The dark grey border is from the background shape and it is visible in the corners on the right but not on the left.

Comment: I found a solution please check if it works or not. check my updated answer

Comment: Yes it solved the border problem nicely. Unfortunately the shadow effect lost .

Comment: can't it be done by padding?
could you post your last layout code so I could test it out

Comment: I have played with padding but was not able to solve it. Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would use LinearLayout so that I could have the text right of the rounded image.
The text is actually two different texts.
So use Weight and then you can put them wherever you want.